# How do you know if your Pokémon has been traded in the GTS?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is there any way to tell whether the Pokémon you put in the GTS has been traded without actually going in and checking? Is there some kind of notification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is none. There are notifications for StreetPass hits and News via the Holo Caster for some events however.

However, you can check whether your Pokemon was traded on GTS besides connecting to GTS by checking your [Pokemon Global Link](http://3ds.pokemon-gl.com) account and checking your logbook.

Answer (score 1):

When I was on my computer, I kept a tab open to my 3ds.pokemon-gl.com account. I hit refresh once in a while, and keep an eye on my logbook. It will say when my pokemon has been traded.